# Mobile version of website with ip address as url

Tags: html, url, ip, webserver, mobile-website

Is it possible to have two website variants, one standard for desktops, and one specifically for mobile when the URL is the external web address? For example the normal address would be http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx/page.HTML
And the mobile variant as something like:
http://m.xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx/page.HTML
Is this possible or would I need to use a m.example.com style address?
And more importantly, if possible how would this be achieved using  Apache 2 on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a m. sub-domain. just use [CSS @media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

[Example](http://www.toptal.com/designers/responsive/introduction-to-responsive-web-design-pseudo-elements-media-queries)

Comment: Or you can just use Html, Css and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use HTML, CSS and JS front-end framework for developing responsive projects on the web such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).